# Saving to CSV file when using Class attribute

Tags: python, class, menu, attributes

Ok so I am trying really hard to get this working. I think I am still not so familiar with the self argument yet, not sure if that matters in this case but I want to append user input once I choose number 1 in the menu and input data that appends to user_list and eventually saves in csv file. But I only get the code <**main**.User object at 0x7f36d7ccdfa0> in the csv file once I put in the data throught the program

```
import csv

user_list = []

class User:
  
  def __init__(self, first, last):
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.email = first + '.' + last + '@expressdelivery.com'


def menu():
  
  while True: 
          print("[1]. Add/remove/update: user to the system.")
          try:
            option = int(input("Choose from the menu: "))
            if option == 1:
              user_list.append(User(first = input("Name: "), last = input("Last: ")))
              with open('User.csv', 'w') as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file)
                writer.writerow(user_list)
                
              return(menu())
            else:
              print("Program quits")
              break
          except:
            print("Error")
menu()
```

Comment: Why do you *expect* something other than `<main.User object at 0x7f36d7ccdfa0>`?

Comment: Am I not supposed to get the input value first and last?

Comment: No. Again, why did you *expect* this? I'm not trying to be difficult, I'm trying to get you to understand.